# Public member "<method>" of type "<module>" not found although the call is performed inside

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, polymorphism

I wrote a module looking like the sample below:

```
Public Module aModule

  Private Sub doSomethingRelevant()
    Dim s As String = "foo"
    Dim o As Object = s
    aModule.performCrashyThing(s) ' Success
    aModule.performCrashyThing(o) ' Error
  End Sub

  Private Sub  performCrashyThing(s as String)
    ' Blah blah
  End Sub

  Private Sub  performCrashyThing(l as Long)
    ' Blah blah
  End Sub

End Module
```

The second call `performCrashyThing(o)` throws an exception:

> Public member "performCrashyThing" of type "aModule" not found.

It won't complain if I turn this subroutine `Public` (without touching the second one using  a `Long` parameter). I don't understand since the calls are performed inside the module.

Comment: Under Option Strict ON directive you cannot do that. Turn off you Option Strict. But as advice create a third sub (with the same name) with an Object parameter

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj, thanks. (I prefere too the third sub solution). Is there some documentation explaining why this is forbidden (especially explaining why making the subroutine public makes a difference)?

Comment: There is not issue around Public or Private. There we are talking for a correct programming mechanism. Many errors comes up in runtime (compiler avoid those). But to be secure our application run perfectly we need to have Option Strict On.
Doing that the compiler tell us “Hey man there is a possible error on runtime”. Take a look here  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj, I answered under your answer.

Comment: There is not a performCrashyThing with a signature for Object.

Comment: If you pass an Object it could be anything. performCrashyThing is expecting either a string or a long. These methods will undoubtedly perform some actions on these parameters that depend on the type of the parameter. For example the overload expecting a string might call Substring on s. An Object does not have a SubString method.

Comment: Please DO NOT turn off Option Strict.

Comment: @Mary The real point of this question is to understand why turning the subroutine into Public makes the error disappear.

Comment: @dbasnett, please see my answer to Mary's comment.

Comment: I changed all three of the methods to public and I still get a red squiggly under the call with an object parameter. With option strict on you don't get an error?

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comments above, Option Strict On is there:
(But you need to take **always ON** and change your methods)[image]

Comment: Thanks, I understand the sample involves late binding, and I read the link you posted below my question. But I still don't understand why making **`Public`** the sub "solves" the error (ie it's not displayed anymore).

Comment: I don’t know what version of VS you have. But the error on wrong parameter (using Option Strict On) comes up in VS 13, VS 17 and VS 19. Ide’s which I use now.  
Maybe you have an older VS and older compiler/framework (MSVC) inside them.

Comment: VS 2010, for legacy reasons. (Added a tag, just in case.)

Comment: I also have VS 2005 installed. Even in this version of VS the error is showed always under Option Strict On also making Public Sub.

Comment: Interesting. I might have missed a point while writing this MVCE.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you were trying to accomplish passing an Object.  Here is some food for thought. I added an object method of performCrashyThing that determines which specific performCrashyThing should be called.

```
Public Module aModule

    Public Sub doSomethingRelevant()
        Dim s As String = "foo"
        Dim o As Object = s
        aModule.performCrashyThing(s)
        aModule.performCrashyThing(o)
        o = 1L
        aModule.performCrashyThing(o)
    End Sub

    Private Sub performCrashyThing(obj As Object)
        If TypeOf obj Is String Then
            performCrashyThing(DirectCast(obj, String))
        ElseIf TypeOf obj Is Long Then
            performCrashyThing(DirectCast(obj, Long))
        Else
            Stop
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub performCrashyThing(s As String)
        ' Blah blah
    End Sub

    Private Sub performCrashyThing(l As Long)
        ' Blah blah
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: It's something more complex using reflection. I loop through some object properties and pass them to a sub. Properties are of a limited type set, and the relevant sub would be called according to the property type. You are suggesting what G3nt_M3caj suggested in a comment below my question.

Comment: @Amessihel - then why are you using Object?  Except for the 'o' of type Object in your OP your code worked.

Comment: Because when you want to retrieve the value of a given property got through reflection you end up using `PropertyInfo.GetValue()`, which returns an `Object` instance. I tried a cast (something like `Convert.ChangeType(pi.GetValue(), pi.GetType())` but it didn't change anything). Of course, I may be doing it wrong.